# How can I insert "and" into a string of citations?

Tags: citing, apa6

I would like to output something like

> see Smith (1999), Jones (2015), and Lovelace (2005).

by doing something like this

```
see \textcite{smith99, jones15, [and] lovelace04}
```

but I can not. Leaving out `[and]` gives me (as most of you know) something like

> see Smith (1999), Jones (2015), Lovelace (2004)

But how can I insert that *and*?

Comment: Do you  use  ̉`biblatex`, and if so, which style?

Comment: I use: \usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

Comment: A minimal working example would be nice…

Comment: \textcite{french15topiCS, love15topiCS, cooper15topiCS} produces:  ``French and Thomas (2015), Love (2015), Cooper and
Peebles (2015)'' \textcite{french15topiCS, love15topiCS, [and] cooper15topiCS} produces: ``French and Thomas (2015), Love (2015), [and] cooper15topiCS''

Comment: Clearly I can do this: \textcite{french15topiCS, love15topiCS} and \textcite{cooper15topiCS} -- and that is what I have been doing, but I am wondering if there is a more general way to put "and" between the penultimate and the ultimate citation in a string of citations.

Comment: There is indeed, but I would like to test with a minimal file, without me having to make a (small) .bib file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23633/discussion-between-wayne-and-bernard).